# Error When Checking Target (Keras)

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, vectorization, imdb

Hi I am following this code along from Deep learning with python Book. I am trying to train a model with pretrained word embeddings on raw IMDB dataset. I get this error how to fix this.

**I followed this process**

**1. Processing the labels of the raw IMDB data**

**2. Tokenizing the text of the raw IMDB data**

**3. Parsing the GloVe word-embeddings file**

**4. Preparing the GloVe word-embeddings matrix**

**5. Defining my model**

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Embedding, Flatten, Dense


model = Sequential()

model.add(Embedding(max_words, embedding_dim, input_length=maxlen))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))

model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.layers[0].set_weights([embedding_matrix])
model.layers[0].trainable = False

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics['acc'])
history = model.fit(x_train,y_train,epochs=10,batch_size=32,validation_data(x_val, y_val))

model.save_weights('pre_trained_glove_model.h5')
```

When I run it I get an error about the last dense layer:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_12 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (100,)
```

When I change the shape of the Dehse layer to 100 it gives me this error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_13 to have shape (100,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

How to fix this error?

It works perfectly without the pre-trained word embedding and it also gives me 86% accuracy

Comment: Post your x_train/val, y_train/val shapes.

Comment: X_train shape = (200,100) ,  y_train.shape = (200,)  ,  x_val = (10000,100) , y_val = (10000 ,100)

Comment: Your y_val shape is wrong. It should be similar to (10000,). I think you are somewhere loading x_val in y_val.